# How to add a folder to Django?

Tags: python, django

So my question looks like this

1. Creating a new project

   ```
    django-admin startproject firstapp
   ```
2. Creating a new app

   ```
    python manage.py startapp blog
   ```
3. So, my question is . I've added a new folder called "projects" within the app "blog"
4. Django doesn't see the folder. How to connect? via INSTALLED_APPS (I've tried it doesn't work)

Comment: Have you added an `__init__.py` file?

Comment: you ran djnago-admin startapp myapp inside project root folder  where manage.py is

Comment: No, I haven't added. I am a new one.

Comment: I have run. I see _init.py__ so it is empty

Comment: the init file should be empty, its purpose is to help django recognize your folder and files in it